# Taking Linux Command as Raw String in Python

Tags: python, linux, string, bash

)I have confirmed my Linux command works in the terminal, however when I try to call it from python it breaks.

The command is a bit long and has lots of single quotes, so I wrapped it around three double quotes (""") so python can interpret as a raw string (or so I thought). However, when I run it I am getting

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

but I have double and tripple checked my single and double quotes and I have no idea where to go from here.

See the test script below

```
import os

os.system("""awk -F ' *[[:alnum:]_]*: *' 'BEGIN         {h="insert_job;box_name;command;owner;permission;condition;description;std_out_file;std_err_file;alarm_if_fail"; print h; n=split(h,F,/;/)} function pr() {if(F[1] in A) {for(i=1;i<=n;i++)printf "%s%s",A[F[i]],(i<n)?";":RS}} /insert_job/  {pr(); delete A} {for(i in F){if($0~"^"F[i])A[F[i]]=$2}} END           {pr()}' ./output/JILS/B7443_dev_jil_20140306104313.csv > /trvapps/autosys/admin/EPS/output/JILS/testout.txt""")
```

FYI I am using Python 2.4.3, hence why I am using os instead of subprocess.

Comment: It's a typo that you didn't close the `(`?

Comment: `"""` would make it a string, but not a raw string. `r"""` would make it [a raw string](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: Albus, a typo. Fixed it, thanks.

Comment: `os.system()` is deprecated in favor of the tools in the `subprocess` module anyhow. Even if you *were* going to use awk for this, `subprocess.Popen(['awk', '-F', awk_script], stdout=open('testout.txt', 'w'))` would be the Right Thing -- that would avoid this bug with `sh -c`, because using `subprocess.Popen()` with an array and no `shell=True` flag doesn't involve a `sh` instance at all.

Comment: @Matt, re: your recent edit, the subprocess module **is** available in Python 2.4.3.

Comment: @Matt ...if you have questions on that subject, see http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.3/lib/module-subprocess.html

Answer (score 2):

For your own sanity, try using `pipes.quote` (or something similar if that doesn't exist in 2.4), `' '.join(words)` and `'\n'.join(lines)` to be able to build up the command rather than using a single complex string if you *have* to put it in Python. A better solution would be to call a script like [@kojiro suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230294/taking-linux-command-as-raw-string-in-python/22230442#comment33755480_22230442).

It looks like you are doing some simple CSV munging. How about checking SO for tips on doing that in Python?

In any case, 400+ characters of `awk` on a single line is enough to make anyone squirm, and doing it in Python, which already has excellent string handling features, is just passing the pain to the next developer. Which will be very angry.

Comment: Or, you know, put the templatized shell script in a separate file.

Comment: +1 for suggesting pure Python. Use `subprocess` to access existing non-Python code, not to embed other languages in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Cramming the awk script into one huge line is awful, and makes it nearly impossible to read and maintain. Don't do that -- if you really must use awk (a dubious claim), write it out on multiple lines, with proper indentation, like you would any other script.

To fix the bug with `sh -c` interpreting things wrong, use the `subprocess` module (passing an argument array and **not** setting `shell=True`) instead of `os.system()`.

```
import subprocess

awk_script = r'''
*[[:alnum:]_]*: *

BEGIN {
   h="insert_job;box_name;command;owner;permission;condition;description;std_out_file;std_err_file;alarm_if_fail";
   print h;
   n=split(h,F,/;/)
}

function pr() {
  if(F[1] in A) {
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      printf "%s%s", A[F[i]], (i<n) ? ";" : RS
  }
}

/insert_job/ {
  pr();
  delete A;
}

{
  for(i in F) {
    if($0~"^"F[i])
      A[F[i]]=$2
  }
}

END {pr()}
'''

exit_status = subprocess.call(['awk', '-F', awk_script],
  stdin=open('./output/JILS/B7443_dev_jil_20140306104313.csv', 'r'),
  stdout=open('/trvapps/autosys/admin/EPS/output/JILS/testout.txt', 'w'))
if exit_status != 0:
  raise RuntimeException('awk failed')
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. I tried running that test, though the script errors out on line "37" when there is only 36 lines. Perhaps the files need to be closed after opening them in your answer?

Comment: @matt, no, the files don't need to be explicitly closed. The only obvious bug I see here is a missing close paren at the end, now fixed.

Comment: @Matt, by the way, "errors out" isn't a very useful description without any information as to just what kind of error is at issue. In the future, please do try to be more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Charles. However, as I stated in my OP subprocess is not supported in my version of python (2.4.3). So, I need to us OS.

Comment: @Matt, that's not correct; the subprocess module was introduced in Python 2.4, and is definitely present in 2.4.3. Also, using the word "stated" is somewhat misleading for something you edited in recently.

Comment: @Matt ...now, what *wasn't* present in 2.4.3 was `check_call()`, but that's easy to replace, and this answer should now be 2.4-compatible.